# Xcode abnormal behavior (conflicting nullability specifier on return types)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am updating a legacy project which was built in objective-c. I am currently battling 2 issues with that project.

1. The legacy project has enabled lot of compiler flags and building the project throws this warning `conflicting nullability specifier on return types, 'nullable' conflicts with existing specifier 'nonnull' for stuff like this - (nullable instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE`
   I understand why it is showing it and I believe it is showing this warning because the project has `--Wnullability-declspec` flag ON.
   I can turn it off and the warning disappears. However, if I put it back then the warning does not come back. I got baffled by it. I cleaned up the project and made sure there are no filters set but still could not figure out why xcode stops showing the warning.
   (I do know the correct fix is not to remove the flag and I know how to fix the issue in the code. I am just amused the xcode stops showing the warnings). So, I am trying to figure how why xcode behaves this way.
2. The warning which is coming is actually in the library header which this project includes.
   I own that library. So, I tried to add that compiler option(`--Wnullability-declspec`) to that libs source code and see if I get the warning. But I don't see that warning in that libs source code.
   So, the other question which I have is why I get the warning in the project which includes this library and not in the actual library.

Comment: Apple has added the **nullable** attributes to ObjC for a better compatibility with strong-typed Swift. Update your library and specify which objects can(not) be `nil` by adding those attributes, too. Suppressing warnings is the wrong way.

Comment: Yep, as I mentioned above the question, I do know how to fix it. I am more interested in those 2 questions and not how to fix it.